# How should we create a login page in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help with describing login page procedure in asp.net mvc. I have created a database and "user table" for storing the username and password.
Help me from creating the stored procedure and else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little too broad, please tell us how far you have gone and what issues you are running into.

Comment: There's a good article from Microsoft that covers this topic:
[Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

Answer (score 0):

> 1
>   **Visual Studio->NEW project->from web->Asp.net web application->name it-> select mvc**
>
> 2
>   **create model-> rename it with project name**
>
> 3
>   **r.c controller->Add->controller->name as LoginController**
>
> 4
>   **Go to App_Start -> RouteConfig -> rename the controller name as LoginController**

```
defaults: new { controller = "login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

> 5
>   ** Go to view, click on Login folder -> add->view->rename as Index**

```
@{
// Layout = "null";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/LoginScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id="pwdpassword" />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="UserLogin()">Login</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

> 6
>   ** Go to script -> R.C add new item -> web -> JavaScript-> rename->LoginScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});

 function UserLogin() {
var logObj = {
    usr_username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
    usr_password: $('#pwdpassword').val(),
}

$ajax({
    url: "/Login/UserValidate",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(logObj),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == true) {
            alert("Login Succesfull");
            LoginRedirect();
        } else {
            alert("Username or password is incorrect");

        }

    }
 })

 }

 function LoginRedirect()
 {
 url="/DemoList/List";
 window.location = url;
 }
```

> 7
>   **Go to Controller -> LoginController->

```
using benzy.demo.mvc.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace benzy.demo.mvc.Controllers
{
public class loginController : Controller
{
    dbs_benzydemoEntities demoCon = new dbs_benzydemoEntities();
    // GET: login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //public JsonResult UserValidateUserValidate(ben_usertable use)
    //{
    //    //    return Json(demoCon.procheckuser( use.usr_username,use.usr_password), 
 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    //    return 
    //}
 }
}
```

> 7
>   **Go to model -> dropdown edmx-> wafdsf.context.tt->wrewe.context.cs->dbs_entity**
>
> 8
>   **stored procedere**
>   CREATE PROCEDURE procheckuser(
>   @name varchar(30),
>   @password varchar(30))
>   AS
>   BEGIN
>   SELECT log_id FROM login WHERE log_username=@name AND log_password=@password
>   END